# MIME type ('text/html') is not executable errors in Chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, mime-types, typechecking

I am trying to add my webpack build.js file to my html page and I keep getting these errors in Chrome:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/public/build.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/public/build.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

**app.js:**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('poopy');
});

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    res.end('success');
});
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Coffee Newsletter</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/" method="post">
        <input type="email" name="email">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./public/build.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**webpack config:**

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    entry: './scripts.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/public',
        filename: 'build.js'
    },
    watch: true

}
```

I have tried using the `historyApiFallback: true` and it didn't fix anything. I have read a lot about people fixing the issue in the HTML script tag being wrong, so maybe there is something I am not seeing. Hopefully someone can help me out! Thanks in advance.

Just to clarify this is where my files are
**Main Folder:** *C:\Users\jake\Documents\project\CoffeeClub\newsletter*

- Public
- app.js
- scripts.js
- webpack.config.js

Inside Public I have these files:

- build.js
- index.html

Comment: see `net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)` mean that `http://localhost:3000/public/js/build.js` not exist

Comment: Is public a directory on your server? Or is it the base directory? Also, there are 2 different paths `/public/js/build.js` and `/public/build.js`

Comment: @tank I just added my file tree to the post to clarify where some files are from what I believe it is unless you can tell me otherwise. And I was moving some files around trying to fix the issue I updated my question with the right locations for files

Comment: @ewwink not sure I mean I can see the file in that directory and I made sure it was spelled the same way as well

Comment: UPDATE: So I think I have narrowed the problem down to my server pulling the html file. When I use:
`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/'))
`
I get the same errors in chrome, yet when I use:
`app.use('/public', express.static('public'));`
I get no chrome errors but the HTML does not load

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> ```
> app.use(express.static('public'));
> ```

So when the browser asks for `/public/build.js` the server gives it `./public/public/build.js`. Since that doesn't exist, it gives it a 404 instead.

One public from the URL, the other from the static base dir.

If you want to include `/public` in the URL, then you have to limit the route of the middleware.

```
app.use('/public', express.static('public'));
```

Comment: that makes sense I just changed it and I am not getting that error anymore! just now that html isnt loading to the server

Comment: also, in my scripts.js file I have a console log that lets me know everything is working and that doesn't show so I am not sure if maybe something else could be wrong there also.

Comment: If the HTML doesn't load, then it won't ask for the script. Since the HTML is inside the public directory, you need to ask for `/public/` instead of `/`. Perhaps you should have gone with the option of not putting `public` in the URL.

Comment: yeah I put the / at the end and it still doesn't seem to be executing the html file

Answer (score 0):

After finding the issue being with my server pulling the HTML I removed the extra directory of public and put it all in the root and it is working perfectly fine now.